# How can I resolve these errors when I open a file with vim?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, ubuntu-20.04

So when I open a file (i.e., `vi examples.R`) on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, I get the following string of errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/mikel/.vimrc:
line    1:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
line    3:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'trevordmiller/nova-vim'
line    4:
E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'jalvesaq/Nvim-R'
line    6:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: call plug#end()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My ~/.vimrc file is:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'trevordmiller/nova-vim'
Plug 'jalvesaq/Nvim-R'

call plug#end()
```

I don't even know where to begin when diagnosing this issue. Do any of you have any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: I'd say the [r] tag is probably not relevant ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker good call. it has been removed.

Comment: Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to the body of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you broke your `.vimrc`, and that your `vi` is just an alias to `vim`. Try either fixing up your configuration (it looks to me that Vundle got messed up somehow) or delete `~/.vimrc` and start again.

Comment: I deleted and recreated ~/.vimrc, and I'm still getting the same errors when type vi examples.R.  However, when I type vim examples.R, I don't get any errors. Why is that? Do I need to change paths somewhere? I updated my ~/.vimrc file in the post to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Remember that when invoked as `vi`, `vim` starts in compatibility mode. I never use it that way, because I generally prefer for `vi` to refer to a minimal Vi and not Neovim or Vim. You might try installing `nvi` and then use `update-alternatives` to get `vi` to refer to `nvi`. Remember that you won't get any fancy feature under `vi` or `nvi`, so you might just want to stick with (n)vim.

Comment: Okay great. Thank you so much for your help! Have a great weekend :)